# GATSBY | MATERIAL UI | ERROR ON BUILD | WebpackError: ReferenceError: document is not defined (from plugin: gatsby-plugin-material-ui)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

Creating a friend a site using Gatsby 4.0 and thought I would use the material UI template. looks nice and works in develop.

I go to build and I get the following errors, I presume its the material UI plugin with using the withStyles function but I am a noob and I can't find a solution online (If I find, at least it's recorded):

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 2.794s
```

ERROR #95312

"document" is not available during server side rendering.

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html

72 |   var _options = options,
73 |       _options$window = _options.window,

> 74 |       window = _options$window === void 0 ? document.defaultView : _options$window;
> | ^
> 75 |   var globalHistory = window.history;
> 76 |
> 77 |   function getIndexAndLocation() {

WebpackError: ReferenceError: document is not defined (from plugin: gatsby-plugin-material-ui)

- index.js:74
  [leighton]/[history]/index.js:74:1
- index.js:82
  [leighton]/[react-router-dom]/index.js:82:26
- index.js:22
  [leighton]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:22:1
- index.js:25
  [leighton]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:25:1
- index.js:31
  [leighton]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:31:1
- index.js:30
  [leighton]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:30:4
- index.js:41
  [leighton]/[decode-uri-component]/index.js:41:1
- gatsby-ssr.js:33
  [leighton]/[gatsby-plugin-material-ui]/gatsby-ssr.js:33:47
- api-runner-ssr.js:92
  leighton/.cache/api-runner-ssr.js:92:28
- static-entry.js:266
  leighton/.cache/static-entry.js:266:11
- dev-404-page.js:15
  leighton/.cache/dev-404-page.js:15:11

Answer (score 0):

> WebpackError: ReferenceError: `document` is not defined (from plugin:
> gatsby-plugin-material-ui)

The source of the issue is in the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering). Summarizing a lot, when your un `gatsby develop` the code is interpreted by the browser, where you can play with `window`, `document`, and other global objects. However, [`gatsby build` runs in the Node server where there's no `window` or `document`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) because has not even been created yet. That's why works in development and not in build mode.

This issue can by easily bypassed by adding the following condition before the usage of those global objects:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
   // code here
}
```

Or wrapping the code in a `useEffect` with empty deps (`[]`). This will ensure that the DOM tree is loaded thus there's a `window` (or `document`) available.

In your case, without any code samples or implementation of `gatsby-plugin-material-ui` it's impossible to know where's the code source of the issue.

Comment: I saw someone write this before. However, its not mentioned where this code goes? On every page? just a config?

Comment: On every use of `document` or `window` that can potentially break the SSG compilation.